# MySQL - sum column value(s) based on row from the same table

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, left-join, pivot

I'm trying to get 'Cash', 'Check' and 'Credit Card' totals in new columns based on ProductID from the same table.

Table - Payments

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
| ProductID |  SaleDate  | PaymentMethod | Amount |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
|         3 | 2012-02-10 | Cash          |     10 |
|         3 | 2012-02-10 | Cash          |     10 |
|         3 | 2012-02-10 | Check         |     15 |
|         3 | 2012-02-10 | Credit Card   |     25 |
|         4 | 2012-02-10 | Cash          |      5 |
|         4 | 2012-02-10 | Check         |      6 |
|         4 | 2012-02-10 | Credit Card   |      7 |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
```

Desired Output -

```
+------------+------+-------+-------------+-------+
| ProductID  | Cash | Check | Credit Card | Total |
+------------+------+-------+-------------+-------+
|          3 |   20 |    15 |          25 |    60 |
|          4 |    5 |     6 |           7 |    18 |
+------------+------+-------+-------------+-------+
```

I've tried LEFT JOINing the same table but haven't had any success. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Unsuccessful and incomplete attempt -

```
SELECT P.ProductID, Sum( PCash.Amount ) AS 'Cash', SUM( PCheck.Amount ) AS 'Check', SUM( PCredit.Amount) AS 'Credit Card' 
FROM Payments AS P 
LEFT JOIN Payments AS PCash ON P.ProductID = PCash.ProductID AND PCash.PaymentMethod = 'Cash'
LEFT JOIN Payments AS PCheck ON P.ProductID = PCheck.ProductID AND PCheck.PaymentMethod = 'Check'
LEFT JOIN Payments AS PCredit ON P.ProductID = PCredit.ProductID AND PCredit.PaymentMethod = 'Credit'
WHERE P.SaleDate = '2012-02-10' GROUP BY ProductID;
```

Comment: Did you use a tool to generate the table UI composed of `-` and `+`s?

Comment: Yeah I liked that too!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I think you're making this a bit more complicated than it needs to be.

```
SELECT
    ProductID,
    SUM(IF(PaymentMethod = 'Cash', Amount, 0)) AS 'Cash',
    -- snip
    SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM
    Payments
WHERE
    SaleDate = '2012-02-10'
GROUP BY
    ProductID
```

Comment: @diEcho I didn't type that part out because I assumed that he could figure that out on his own without any trouble

Comment: I want on same `SaleDate` and same `PaymentMethod` sum of amount else continue.

Comment: Kudos @Explosion Pills, You saved my day, much appreciated answer but cant give enough but +1

Answer (score 15):

This might be seen as a little complex but does exactly what you want

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(p.`ProductID`) AS ProductID,
  SUM(pl.CashAmount) AS Cash,
  SUM(pr.CashAmount) AS `Check`,
  SUM(px.CashAmount) AS `Credit Card`,
  SUM(pl.CashAmount) + SUM(pr.CashAmount) +SUM(px.CashAmount) AS Amount
FROM
  `payments` AS p 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProductID,PaymentMethod , IFNULL(Amount,0) AS CashAmount FROM payments WHERE PaymentMethod = 'Cash' GROUP BY ProductID , PaymentMethod ) AS pl 
    ON pl.`PaymentMethod` = p.`PaymentMethod` AND pl.ProductID = p.`ProductID`
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProductID,PaymentMethod , IFNULL(Amount,0) AS CashAmount FROM payments WHERE PaymentMethod = 'Check' GROUP BY ProductID , PaymentMethod) AS pr 
    ON pr.`PaymentMethod` = p.`PaymentMethod` AND pr.ProductID = p.`ProductID`
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProductID, PaymentMethod , IFNULL(Amount,0) AS CashAmount FROM payments WHERE PaymentMethod = 'Credit Card' GROUP BY ProductID , PaymentMethod) AS px 
    ON px.`PaymentMethod` = p.`PaymentMethod` AND px.ProductID = p.`ProductID`
GROUP BY p.`ProductID` ;
```

Output

```
ProductID | Cash | Check | Credit Card | Amount
-----------------------------------------------
    3     | 20   |  15   |   25        |  60
    4     | 5    |  6    |   7         |  18
```

#### SQL Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 3):

SUM CASE using example:

```
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT(p.`ProductID`) AS ProductID,
  SUM(IF(p.`PaymentMethod`='Cash',Amount,0)) AS Cash_,
  SUM(IF(p.`PaymentMethod`='Check',Amount,0)) AS Check_,
  SUM(IF(p.`PaymentMethod`='Credit Card',Amount,0)) AS Credit_Card_,
  SUM( CASE PaymentMethod 
      WHEN 'Cash' THEN Amount
      WHEN 'Check' THEN Amount
      WHEN 'Credit Card' THEN Amount
     END) AS Total
FROM
  `payments` AS p 
GROUP BY p.`ProductID`;
```

SQL FIDDLE:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23d07d/18

[image: Result and Table view]