# Summing up values from a single table column using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I would like you know how I can sum up all values from a single table column based on a specific constraint. What I mean is this, imagine a table called payments, the payments table has three columns; ID, type of payment and amount. ID is not a primary key so it can duplicate. So let's say there are four entries under one particular ID and I want to get the total for amount for that ID. How can I do it? Thought a while loop would work but tried everything I could think of and it didn't. Please help! Final school project

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - sum column value(s) based on row from the same table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805851/mysql-sum-column-values-based-on-row-from-the-same-table)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql you can use the sum function as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.ID) FROM db1.tblmoney AS t1 WHERE t1.ID = '1';
```

This will select the sum total of column "ID" in all rows within db1.tblmoney with the ID of 1. If on the other hand you are trying to get a count of the rows with that ID you can use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.*) FROM db1.tblmoney AS t1 WHERE t1.ID = '1';
```

The different in these two statements is SUM with get the added values of all ID

So if you have 2 rows of id ='1' you will get 2 if you have two rows of id = '2' you will get 4

Whereas with Count() it will count the number of rows matching your select: 2 rows of id ='1' you will get 2 if you have two rows of id = '2' you will get 2.