# mysql pivot table by date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display results of a payment table containing the sum of specific columns by day;

```
payment id | payment_actual_timestamp | payment type | amount
1          | 2015-11-23 13:01:20      | AUTH         | 0.16
2          | 2015-11-23 13:07:20      | AUTH         | 23.65
3          | 2015-11-24 08:07:20      | VOID         | 19.24
4          | 2015-11-24 13:45:20      | AUTH         | 0.65
5          | 2015-11-24 16:34:10      | REFUND       | 1.20
6          | 2015-11-25 13:07:20      | SETTLE       | 4.40
```

What i'd like to display is the following;

```
Date       | SETTLE | AUTH | VOID | REFUND
2015-11-23 | 0.00   | 23.81| 0.00 | 0.00
2015-11-24 | 0.00   | 0.65 | 19.24| 1.20
2015-11-25 | 4.40   | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00
```

is there a way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805851/mysql-sum-column-values-based-on-row-from-the-same-table

Comment: please show us what you tried and what you get

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Do the SUMMING in MySQL, and the PIVOTING (and accounting for missing values) in PHP

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `conditional aggregation` with `sum` and `case`:

```
select date(payment_actual_timestamp), 
   sum(case when payment_type = 'SETTLE' then amount end) settleamt,
   sum(case when payment_type = 'AUTH' then amount end) authamt,
   sum(case when payment_type = 'VOID' then amount end) voidamt,
   sum(case when payment_type = 'REFUND' then amount end) refundamt
from yourtable
group by date(payment_actual_timestamp)
```