# How to sum various rows based on constraining various columns

Tags: mysql

I would like to add all the `values` for a given `sensor` of a given `machine` that are on the same day on a MySQL table. If todays date is the 17/10/2016 and the table has the following data:

```
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
|      timestamp    +  value  +  sensor | machine |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 10/10/16 01:20:23 |   10    |    1    |    20   |   
| 10/10/16 02:33:05 |   23    |    1    |    20   |
| 11/10/16 03:14:40 |   17    |    1    |    20   |
| 11/10/16 05:53:00 |   99    |    1    |    20   |
| 11/10/16 06:29:20 |   32    |    1    |    20   |
| 11/10/16 07:10:28 |   23    |    2    |    20   |
| 11/10/16 10:00:05 |   45    |    1    |    20   |
| 12/10/16 03:30:00 |   12    |    1    |    20   |
| 12/10/16 14:00:43 |   10    |    1    |    20   |
| 12/10/16 16:40:12 |   89    |    1    |    20   |
| 12/10/16 20:00:45 |   87    |    1    |    20   |
| 12/10/16 23:42:23 |   24    |    2    |    20   |
| 13/10/16 14:02:00 |   97    |    1    |    20   |
| 14/10/16 03:03:04 |   04    |    1    |    20   |
| 14/10/16 15:56:00 |   12    |    1    |    20   |
| 15/10/16 22:18:23 |   93    |    1    |    20   |
| 16/10/16 12:29:45 |   23    |    1    |    20   |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want to get the following out put.

```
+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+
|    timestamp    +  value  + sensor  | machine |
+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+
|     10/10/16    |   33    |    1    |    20   |  
|     11/10/16    |   193   |    1    |    20   |  
|     12/10/16    |   198   |    1    |    20   |  
|     13/10/16    |   99    |    1    |    20   |  
|     14/10/16    |   16    |    1    |    20   |  
|     15/10/16    |   93    |    1    |    20   |  
|     16/10/16    |   23    |    1    |    20   |  
+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I would like to add all the `values` for given `sensor` for given `machine`, and grouped by the date. I have tried by looking at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805851/mysql-sum-column-values-based-on-row-from-the-same-table), but had far too many errors.

**Q:** How could I do MySQL query to get this type of output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will at all the values for a date, and return the date with corresponding summing of values for that particular date.

```
SELECT DATE(  `timestamp` ) DateOnly, SUM(  `value` ) AS  `value` ,  `sensor` ,  `machine` 
FROM my_table
WHERE  `sensor` = 3
AND  `machine` = 20
GROUP BY DateOnly,  `machine` ,  `sensor`
```

It will be grouped just by date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT date, SUM(value) as value, sensor, machine
FROM my_table
WHERE senson=1 AND machine=20
GROUP BY date
```

You can group by several columns, so for example if you want the table of all sensors and machines (instead of a single one), you could use:

```
SELECT date, SUM(value) as value, sensor, machine
FROM my_table
GROUP BY date, sensor, machine
```